# PlayFramework 2.5.12 JPAApi inject error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inject, playframework-2.5

When I try to make an injection, I see a error.
Example of integration I took from the [official site](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA). 
Instead of `"hibernate-entitymanager`" I use `"hibernate-core"`. However, with the `"hibernate-entitymanager"` the same errors.

**Versions**

*hibernate-core - 5.2.8*

*play - 2.5.12*

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingContext;)V
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.<init>(DefaultJPAApi.java:54)
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.class(DefaultJPAApi.java:35)
  while locating play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider
  while locating play.db.jpa.JPAApi
    for field at controllers.api.UsersApi.jpaApi(UsersApi.java:20)
  at controllers.api.UsersApi.class(UsersApi.java:20)
  while locating controllers.api.UsersApi
    for field at controllers.api.ApiFe.usersApi(ApiFe.java:34)
  while locating controllers.api.ApiFe
    for parameter 27 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:136)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
    for parameter 0 at play.DefaultApplication.<init>(DefaultApplication.java:30)
  at play.DefaultApplication.class(DefaultApplication.java:30)
  while locating play.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.Application

1 error]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:180)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
```

**application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://dev-box-2:3306/localbase?characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false"
db.default.user=test
db.default.password=test
db.default.bonecp.logStatements=true
db.default.bonecp.partitionCount=10
db.default.bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition=10
db.default.bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition=1
db.default.bonecp.connectionTimeout=3 seconds

db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      javaJpa,
      cache,
      javaWs,
      "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "5.2.8.Final",
      ...
```

**class**

```
@Singleton
public class UsersApi implements Mappings {

    @Inject
    JPAApi jpaApi;

    ...
}
```

Comment: so Play is calling some Hibernate method which is not present any more in the version of Hibernate you are using. Consequently ask Play why they are calling proprietary methods when allegedly using the JPA API (where you would not need to do such a thing)

Answer (score 0):

I have a recent project that works with `"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.2.8.Final"`

As per @niel-stockton's comment, I dont see anything in DefaultJPAApi class that uses hibernate directly

```
package play.db.jpa;

import play.db.DBApi;
import play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Default implementation of the JPA API.
 */
public class DefaultJPAApi implements JPAApi {
```

Below are my current configurations. I am  using Oracle as DB

**build.sbt**

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.0.3",
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa,
  cache,
  json,
  javaWs,
  "com.typesafe.play.modules" %% "play-modules-redis" % "2.5.0" exclude("redis.clients" ,"jedis"),
  "redis.clients" % "jedis" % "2.9.0",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.2.8.Final",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "21.0",
  "org.opensaml" % "opensaml" % "2.5.3"
)
```

My `application.conf` contains a setting for oracle matching in my `local-db.conf`

**application.conf**

```
play.db.default = "oracle"
```

Playframework by default uses HikariCP, so below configuration applies to HikariCP

my **local-db.conf**

```
evolutionplugin = disabled

jpa {
  default = devPersistenceUnit
}

db {
  oracle {
    # You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
    jndiName = LocalDevDS
    # Set a connection's default autocommit setting
    autocommit = true
    hikaricp {
      dataSourceClassName = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

      dataSource {
        serverName = ${DB_HOST}
        user = ${DB_USER}
        password = ${DB_PASS}
        databaseName = ${DB_NAME}
        portNumber = ${DB_PORT}
        networkProtocol = tcp
        driverType = thin
      }
      maximumPoolSize = 8
      registerMbeans = true
      # 15 minutes
      maxLifetime = 450000
      # 5 minutes
      idleTimeout = 300000
      connectionTimeout = 60000
    }
  }
}
```

**local.conf**

```
include "application.conf"
include "local-db.conf"
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.12")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-twirl" % "1.1.1")
```

** persistence.xml **

```
<persistence-unit name="devPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
  <non-jta-data-source>LocalDevDS</non-jta-data-source>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

If you want to use BoneCP there is some configuration change needed
as per https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsJDBC

```
play.db.pool=bonecp
play.db.prototype.bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition = 50
```

Here `prototype` is the default name given to the Pool configuration. You can call it anything, I am calling it `oracle` in my config

Hope it fixes your issue.